# How to get related resource?

Tags: tastypie

I have models:

```py
class Article(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    symbol = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

    . . .

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s (%s)' % (self.name, self.symbol)


class ArticleRel(models.Model):
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    create = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article)

    . . .

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.id)
```

and resources:

```py
class ArticleResource(ModelResource):
    owner = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'owner')

    class Meta:
        queryset = Article.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'articles'
        serializer = Serializer()
        authorization = Authorization()
        filtering = {
            'owner': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
        }
        always_return_data = True

    def prepend_urls(self):
        return [
            url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<id>\d+)/$" % self._meta.resource_name, self.wrap_view('dispatch_detail'), name="api_dispatch_detail"),
        ]


class ArticleRelResource(ModelResource):
    article = fields.ForeignKey(ArticleResource, 'article')

    class Meta:
        queryset = ArticleRel.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'article_rels'
        serializer = Serializer()
        authorization = Authorization()
        filtering = {
            'article': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
        }
        always_return_data = True

    def prepend_urls(self):
        return [
            url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<id>\d+)/$" % self._meta.resource_name, self.wrap_view('dispatch_detail'), name="api_dispatch_detail"),
        ]
```

and now: how to set this resources so as to get articles with all article_rels in one query?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood the question.
If you meant you wanted to get both article_rels and articles, you can use full=true in the foreign key field.

```
article = fields.ForeignKey(ArticleResource, 'article', full=True)
```

as stated in the documentation - http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#full

Keep in mind of the overhead time of the extra db queries.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:

```py
def dehydrate(self, bundle):
    bundle.data['rels'] = [ar.__dict__ for ar in ArticleRel.objects.filter(article__id=bundle.data['id'])]
    return bundle
```